# discord.py: How do I block a command from executing?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command, that disable specific commands in specific channels.
So, I save this in a json file. Then I want to check, if a command is executed and if this command is in the json file. If this command is in the json file it should print a message. Otherwise it should execute the command.

My Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    with open('commandchannels.json', 'r') as fcheck:
        check = json.load(fcheck)
    if f'{ctx.guild.id}' in check.keys():
        if f'{ctx.channel.id}' in check[f'{ctx.guild.id}']:
            if f'{ctx.command}' in check[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f'{ctx.channel.id}']:

                print('command disabled')

            else:
                exec(ctx.command)

        else:
            exec(ctx.command)

    else:
        exec(ctx.command)
```

But the bot prints "command disabled" and execute the command.

My Json File:

```
{
    "673600173615611913": {
        "722467477031878716": [
            "kick"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should do it inside `if` instead of `else` - `if .... in .... : exec(...) else print(...)`. OR you should use `not` - `if ... not in ....` Or maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables and what you get `print( f'{ctx.channel.id}' in check[f'{ctx.guild.id}'] )`, etc. It is called "print debuging"

Comment: BTW: if `ctx.command` is a string then you don't need `if f'{ctx.command}' in ...` but simply `if ctx.command in ...`

Comment: I don't know 100% what you mean. I have to use `if ... in ... :` - `else` because I want to check if the guild id is in the json file. If the guild id is in the json file it should check if the channel id is in the json file and so on. If one of them not in the json file it should execute the command.

Comment: Or can you give me an example?

Comment: you should use `print()` to check values in variables - maybe there is something different then you expect and then your `if/else` doesn't work. it is called "print debuging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: BTW: maybe it could be simpler `if ... and ... and ...:  print(...) else: exec(...)` - it will need only one `else`. OR use `return` after `print()` and then you can use `exec()` after `if` without `else`.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is when you add the command to your json just use `command.update()` to disable the command. This makes it so nobody can run the command. Once you remove the command from your json use the same function to enable the command. To do this:

```
#first get the command instance
command = bot.get_command('COMMAND NAME')


#to disable the command
command.update(enabled=False)

#to enable the command
command.update(enabled=True)
```

discord.py `command.update()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=disable#discord.ext.commands.Command.update